# How do I choose the download location in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: download, microsoft-teams

When I download a file some has posted in a Teams chat, the file just downloads to my "Downloads" folder.

In every web browser I've ever used, there is an option to have it ask you each time where you want a particular file to be downloaded to. Or, at the very minimum, there is a way to change the download folder that the browser uses.

How can I do this in Teams?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE! Microsoft heard our prayers and delivered!

As of now, this feature has been added (and more).
Not only can you set the default download location, you can have it prompt you for each file downloaded.

I am not sure which versions specifically but mine (which has it) is currently 1.6.00.33567 (12/5/23) running on Windows 11 22R2.

***Going to settings*** now shows the following: (WOOT WOOT!)

[image: Teams Settings]

I hope this makes other people happy too.

Comment: *Sigh* that's what I was beginning to think. Thanks for the confirmation.
Teams is such garbage.

Comment: Teams is real garbage.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas ah yeah unfortunately I am on Ubuntu and that option doesn't exist for us it seems. My solution is to open my downloads in the browser and then do "save as" from there, because I still have absolutely no idea where Teams is sending them by default...

Answer (score 3):

Seems that they finally implemented it:

[image]

My version is `Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.6754 (64-bit). It was last updated on 03/04/2023.`

Comment: Shoot @golimar .. I didn't see this until I updated mine above.  I gave you +1 (the best I can do).